# Check if string contains only Unicode values [\u0030-\u0039] or [\u0660-\u0669]

Tags: java, regex, unicode, java-8

I need to check, in java, if a string is composed only of Unicode values [\u0030-\u0039] or [\u0660-\u0669]. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I'd probably create a simple collection of allowed characters, iterate over all the characters in the string and check if they are in that collection.

Comment: can characters between this two sets be mixed? I assume they should not, because these are numbers from two different numbersystems

Comment: @Predicate There won't be any inter mixing of the two number systems. Currently my data only comprises of Basic Latin and Arabic Unicode characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use \x for unicode characters:

```
^([\x{0030}-\x{0039}\x{0660}-\x{0669}]+)$
```

if the patternt should match an empty string too, use * instead of +

Use this if you dont want to allows mixing characters from both sets you provided:

```
^([\x{0030}-\x{0039}]+|[\x{0660}-\x{0669}]+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/xqWL4q/6

As mentioned by Holger in comments below. `\x{0030}-\x{0039}` is equivalent with `[0-9]`. So could be substituted and would be more readable.

Comment: Usually you can just use the `\u` escapes as well. Saves you from doubling every \ in the string.

Comment: @Joey you don’t even need `\u` escapes to express characters as simple as `'0'` and `'9'`. Further, it’s not necessary to use `|` to combine to character ranges when `[…]` does already support specifying multiple character ranges. Using `[…]` with two ranges eliminates the need for grouping, while the anchors are only needed when using the pattern for a search like operation, like in the online regex tester, whereas e.g. calling `matches` on a string doesn’t need them. Makes the entire operation as simple as [`string.matches("[0-9٠-٩]*")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60598359/2711488)…

Comment: true about the "|" , the \u in the ascii number is in my opinion also redundant, but the op wanted it in this way.

Comment: I am not sure, but your code alows mixing different types of digit, which with high percentage is not wished.

Comment: @Predicate I provided an alternative in my answer, which is simply using two `matches` operations. Since both, the regex matching and Java’s `||` operator are short circuiting, there is no significant performance difference. The only difference is the treatment of empty strings which I consider “composed only of” the specified characters. I’m not sure whether the OP will ever clarify the actual needs. There was enough time…

Comment: @Holger No problem. I was just pointing you to the pitfall you previously proposed solution could fall. But you composed a new one, so everything is fine.)

Answer (score 4):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60597121/check-if-string-contains-only-unicode-values-u0030-u0039-or-u0660-u0669/60598359#comment107206281_60597121), it’s not clear whether you want to check for probably mixed occurrences of these digits or check for either of these ranges.

A simple check for mixed digits would be `string.matches("[0-9٠-٩]*")` or to avoid confusing changes of the read/write direction, or if your source code encoding doesn’t support all characters, `string.matches("[0-9\u0660-\u669]*")`.

Checking whether the string matches either range, can be done using
`string.matches("[0-9]*")||string.matches("[٠-٩]*")` or
`string.matches("[0-9]*")||string.matches("[\u0660-\u669]*")`.

An alternative would be
`string.chars().allMatch(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c >= '٠' && c <= '٩')`.
Or to check for either,  `string.chars().allMatch(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9') || string.chars().allMatch(c -> c >= '٠' && c <= '٩')`

Answer (score 2):

Since these codepoints represent numerals in two different unicode blocks,
I suggest to check if respective character is a numeral:

```
boolean isNumerals(String s) {
    return !s.chars().anyMatch(v -> !Character.isDigit(v));
}
```

This will definitely match **more** than asked for, but in some cases or in more controlled environment it may be useful to make code more readable.

(edit)

Java API also allows to determine a unicode block of a specific character:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock arabic = Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC;
Character.UnicodeBlock latin = Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN;

boolean isValidBlock(String s) {
    return s.chars().allMatch(v ->
            Character.UnicodeBlock.of(v).equals(arabic) ||
                    Character.UnicodeBlock.of(v).equals(latin)

    );
}
```

Combined with the check above will give exact result OP has asked for.
On the plus side - higher abstraction gives more flexibility, makes code more readable and is not dependent on exact encoding of string passed.

Comment: I am not sure, but  i will assume your code will macth more characters than desired. There are more characters in unicode that isDigit == true. Means your code is only partially correct.

Comment: It definitely will match more than you asked for, but in real life this may be not an issue, especially if you build a software with such specific locale requirements. 

For instance, if you validate user input what's the chance that you get numerals in more than, say, two unicode blocks? Vast majority has just two keyboard layouts - native and en-us.

Comment: The op was very specific about what should match. We dont know the environment. He is already using two different number systems, i could be there are more used. Your code could provide wrong results. At least you should clearly write it out in your answer if you are posting this solution

Comment: @Predicate, agreed.
Added disclaimer to the answer to clarify my point.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution by using regex:
(see also lot better explained by @Predicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/60597367/12558456)

```
private boolean legalRegex(String s) {
    return s.matches("^([\u0030-\u0039]|[\u0660-\u0669])*$");
}
```

faster but ugly solution: (needs a hashset of allowed chars)

```
private boolean legalCharactersOnly(String s) {
        for (char c:s.toCharArray()) {
            if (!allowedCharacters.contains(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works without regex for arbitrary unicode code points (outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane).

```
private final Set<Integer> codePoints = new HashSet<Integer>();

public boolean test(String string) {
    for (int i = 0, codePoint = 0; i < string.length(); i += Character.charCount(codePoint)) {
        codePoint = string.codePointAt(i);

        if (!codePoints.contains(codePoint)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```